# c# File.Exists returns true on inexistent file

Tags: c#

I am trying to detect the existence of a file, I am using the System.IO.File.Exists function from C#, so, if I do `File.Exists("file.txt");` it returns TRUE, although the file does NOT exist!!
What is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure that you checked the default folder of the project? try full path.

Comment: Check `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. I bet that it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Are you sure that the file doesn't exist? Maybe it's a hidden file and that's why you can't see it?

Comment: Have you checked in your current working directory whether file.txt is present or not ?

Comment: Doesn't it by default get the current path?

Comment: In the future use procmon to diagnose problems like these; you would have been able to diagnose the problem yourself immediately by watching which file was actually found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the method is returning true, then the file does exist.

However, you are probably not looking at the same location as the `File.Exists` command.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory.

As you are not specifying the full path to the file, the current working directory is being used to determine if the file exists; and it likely does exist there.

Comment: In my case I have printed the working directory which is the Debug in which the file doesn't exist. However the check if (!File.Exists(DbConfigFile)) doesn't trigger at all. Strange.

Comment: @thanos.a Without more details it is difficult to identify your issue, but please be aware *current* working directory is not the same is the working directory.  It may change during execution.  I would recommend you use `Path.GetFullPath` method to try and identify where the system is looking for the file.  This may help you identify where the system is looking vs where you are expecting the system to be looking.

Answer (score 2):

When you use just the fileName, it will find in the same local where it is executing. You have to pass the full path, for sample:

```
if (File.Exists("C:\\temp\\file.txt"))
{
  // exists, use it
}
else
{
  // does not exists
}
```

Comment: You are right, it works if I give it the current path

Comment: Not the case for me. I know for a fact the file doesn't exist (because I just deleted it to get the app to create a new one) and its still returning true. My path is `C:\myApp\Data\myApp.mdf`

Comment: I have the same issue with @Ortund. I am renaming my db.config to something.config and I also delete it from the debug directory which is the current working directory as it is printed out by this command Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

Then I check with (!File.Exists(DbConfigFile)) and it doesn't trigger. the DbConfigFile variable has "\\db.config" value when I check it with the debugger.