# System.IO.File.Exists always return true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if file is present on the server or not & warn use if file exists, so that he can rename the file & upload again. but my code always returns true even if i add `!` to the `System.IO.File.Exists`

This code is for ASP.net webform application

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
if (System.IO.File.Exists("../pdf/news/" + FileUploadControl.FileName))
{
    ViewState["_fileName"] = null;
    StatusLabel.Text = "File with this name already exsists, Please rename file and Upload gain";
}
else
{
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../pdf/news/") + filename);
    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    //_fileName = FileUploadControl.FileName;
    ViewState["_fileName"] = FileUploadControl.FileName;
}
```

I am sure i am doing something wrong but not able to figure out what.

Comment: Duplicate question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592187/c-sharp-file-exists-returns-true-on-inexistent-file. If it returns true, it means that it does exist. EDIT: The linked question is an update to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308421/file-exists-returning-true-for-a-file-that-doesnt-exist

Comment: @RyanAlexander What?  Does _not_ exist?  I don't think so...

Comment: @RyanAlexander, I am uploading `.PDF` for which i am checking logic separately. in above mentioned code i am trying to check if `xyz.pdf` already exists in that folder.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for for `Server.MapPath("../pdf/news/" + FileUploadControl.FileName)`?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` gives the same result it always returns true...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that you did not use `Server.MapPath` before the exists check. Where is it looking? We don't know. But since you *intend* doing that later: move it earlier:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../pdf/news/"), filename);
```

And use `path` for **both** the exists check and final creation.

Note that editing files inside your web app tree is a bad idea:

- it can trigger an app-pool restart
- it is a potential hack attack-vector
- it doesn't scale to a cluster

Comment: You have mentioned some very important points `Note that editing files inside your web app tree is a bad idea`. can you please tell me what approach should i take to address issue which you have mentioned. This can be of great help to other user also. I will also try to search for the best way. But pointer from your side or a reference article would be fine.

Comment: store them *elsewhere*; any document archive would do - that could be as simple as a file tree **outside** your web tree, or it could be a share on a NAS/SAN, or it could be a CDN, or it could be a RDBMS or NOSQL store. Plenty of options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are not mapping the path in the check.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../pdf/news/" + FileUploadControl.FileName)))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something I encountered. If a file stream already exists then it will create a 0 byte file in the directory. That then gets detected by your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).